# Converting Javascript datatables to use Opal in Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatables, opalrb

I am using the [ajax-datatables-rails](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails).  Below is the JS for my datatable.  I want to convert the javascript into equivalent Opal.rb.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#organizations-datatable');
  var token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
  table.DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
      "url": "/organizations/datatable.json",
      "type": 'POST',
      "beforeSend": function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token)
        }
    },
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "destroy": true,
    "columns": [
      {"data": "name"},
      {"data": "desc"},
      {"data": "industry"},
      {"data": "tags"}
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": 25
  });
});
```

It includes adding the CSRF token to the ajax request for data.

I would like all of our javascript to be written as opal for readability, etc. Please don't debate that choice, I only care to understand how to get this working as Opalrb via opal/rails-ujs/opal-jquery

The below Opal does not achieve the same as the above JS.  Can anyone help me understand why?

```rb
Element.expose :DataTable

Document.ready? do
  token     = Element['meta[name=csrf-token]'].attr('content');
  settings  = {
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": {
        "url": "/organizations/datatable.json",
        "type": 'POST',
        "beforeSend": lambda do
          xhr = `new window.XMLHttpRequest()`
          xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token)
        end 
      },
      "pagingType": "full_numbers",
      "destroy": true,
    "columns": [
      {"data": "name"},
      {"data": "desc"},
      {"data": "industry"},
      {"data": "tags"}
    ]
    }
  Element['#organizations-datatable'].DataTable(settings.to_n)

end
```

What am I missing here? Why isn't this Opal any good?

**Edit: This is what my route for this looks like, this ensures POST works for this:**

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    concern :with_datatable do
        post 'datatable', on: :collection
    end
    resources :organizations,   concerns: [:with_datatable]
end
```

This is my related controller and datatable code using the gem:

```rb
class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @title              = "Organizations"
        @page_description   = "Organization data warehouse"
        @page_icon          = "institution"
        @organization       = Organization.new
        @load               = {data_table: true}
        @menu               = Menu.new 

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: OrganizationDatatable.new(params) }
      end

    end

    def datatable
        logger.ap "datatable params: #{params}"
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: OrganizationDatatable.new(params) }
        end
    end

    def get_raw_records
        Organization.all
    end
    def create

    end
    def edit

    end
    def destroy

    end

    def show    
    end

    def update
    end

    def new
    end
end
```

Here is the datatable

```rb
class OrganizationDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::ActiveRecord

  extend Forwardable
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper

  def_delegator :@view, :link_to

  def view_columns
    # Declare strings in this format: ModelName.column_name
    # or in aliased_join_table.column_name format

    @view_columns ||= {
      # id:       { source: "Organization.id"           },
      name:     { source: "Organization.name",cond: :like, searchable: true, orderable: true          },
      desc:     { source: "Organization.description",cond: :like, searchable: true, orderable: true   },
      industry: { source: "Organization.industry",cond: :like, searchable: true, orderable: true      },
      tags:     { source: "Organization.tag_list", searchable: false, orderable: false      }
    }
  end

  def data
    records.map do |record|
      {
        id:       record.id,
        name:     record.name,
        desc:     truncate(record.description,length: 240, separator: ' '),
        industry: record.industry,
        tags:     record.decorate.buttonize_tags,
        DT_RowId: record.id
      }
    end
  end

  def get_raw_records
    Organization.all
  end

end
```

Comment: what is the difference between the two results? I advise you to set a `binding.pry` and check every variables values in your `Opal` script

Comment: what is exactly not working properly? could it be related with `beforeSend`?

Comment: The datatable is not populated. Yes.  It's basically 3 lines of code in JS and 5 in Opal.  I don't see a mistake.  There aren't any errors in console that I see.

Comment: the problem is not included in the question you posted. You need to add more information and better troubleshoot this issue. Currently you are guessing that the problem is in those 3 lines of Opal code, but you have no clue until you correctly troubleshoot it. Try creating a simple `Opal` example and see if it works, then try to `console.log` with `Opal` code the `DataTable` object... and step by step add functionalities until you see exactly what breaks so that you have clear clue of what is happening.. otherwise we could just try to guess.

Comment: You have a silent error which is hard to troubleshoot. Which are the possible mistakes in `Javascript` which cause silent errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will start with pointing few mistakes in your code ,

1. The code in beforeSend is problematic please refer to [supplying-an-xhr-method](https://github.com/opal/opal-jquery#supplying-an-xhr-method), change it to the below code,

   `"beforeSend": lambda do |xhr|`

   `` `xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token)` ``

enclose xhr statements in ( ` ) backticks like above statement

2. columns should have two dimensional array rather than array of objects,

   `"columns": [
         ["data": "name"],
         ["data": "desc"],
         ["data": "industry"],
         ["data": "tags"]
   ]`

Rest of the code looks fine.

Below is the tested code,

```
Element.expose :DataTable
Document.ready? do
  token     = Element['meta[name=csrf-token]'].attr('content');
  settings  = {
      "ajax": {
        "url": "/data.json",
        "type": 'POST',
        "beforeSend": lambda do |xhr|
          `xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token)`
        end 
      },
      "pagingType": "full_numbers",
      "destroy": true,
    "columns": [
      ["data": "Name"],
      ["data": "Position"],
      ["data": "Office"],
      ["data": "Extn."],
      ["data": "Start"],
      ["data": "Salary"]
    ]
    }
  Element['#organizations-datatable'].DataTable(settings.to_n)

end
```

Make sure you have `data.json` file in public folder of rails app, and contents as follows,

```
{
    "data": [
      [
        "Tiger Nixon",
        "System Architect",
        "Edinburgh",
        "5421",
        "2011/04/25",
        "$320,800"
      ],
      [
        "Garrett Winters",
        "Accountant",
        "Tokyo",
        "8422",
        "2011/07/25",
        "$170,750"
      ],
      [
        "Ashton Cox",
        "Junior Technical Author",
        "San Francisco",
        "1562",
        "2009/01/12",
        "$86,000"
      ],
      [
        "Cedric Kelly",
        "Senior Javascript Developer",
        "Edinburgh",
        "6224",
        "2012/03/29",
        "$433,060"
      ],
      [
        "Airi Satou",
        "Accountant",
        "Tokyo",
        "5407",
        "2008/11/28",
        "$162,700"
      ],
      [
        "Brielle Williamson",
        "Integration Specialist",
        "New York",
        "4804",
        "2012/12/02",
        "$372,000"
      ],
      [
        "Herrod Chandler",
        "Sales Assistant",
        "San Francisco",
        "9608",
        "2012/08/06",
        "$137,500"
      ],
      [
        "Rhona Davidson",
        "Integration Specialist",
        "Tokyo",
        "6200",
        "2010/10/14",
        "$327,900"
      ],
      [
        "Colleen Hurst",
        "Javascript Developer",
        "San Francisco",
        "2360",
        "2009/09/15",
        "$205,500"
      ],
      [
        "Sonya Frost",
        "Software Engineer",
        "Edinburgh",
        "1667",
        "2008/12/13",
        "$103,600"
      ],
      [
        "Jena Gaines",
        "Office Manager",
        "London",
        "3814",
        "2008/12/19",
        "$90,560"
      ],
      [
        "Quinn Flynn",
        "Support Lead",
        "Edinburgh",
        "9497",
        "2013/03/03",
        "$342,000"
      ],
      [
        "Charde Marshall",
        "Regional Director",
        "San Francisco",
        "6741",
        "2008/10/16",
        "$470,600"
      ],
      [
        "Haley Kennedy",
        "Senior Marketing Designer",
        "London",
        "3597",
        "2012/12/18",
        "$313,500"
      ],
      [
        "Tatyana Fitzpatrick",
        "Regional Director",
        "London",
        "1965",
        "2010/03/17",
        "$385,750"
      ],
      [
        "Michael Silva",
        "Marketing Designer",
        "London",
        "1581",
        "2012/11/27",
        "$198,500"
      ],
      [
        "Paul Byrd",
        "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)",
        "New York",
        "3059",
        "2010/06/09",
        "$725,000"
      ],
      [
        "Gloria Little",
        "Systems Administrator",
        "New York",
        "1721",
        "2009/04/10",
        "$237,500"
      ],
      [
        "Bradley Greer",
        "Software Engineer",
        "London",
        "2558",
        "2012/10/13",
        "$132,000"
      ],
      [
        "Dai Rios",
        "Personnel Lead",
        "Edinburgh",
        "2290",
        "2012/09/26",
        "$217,500"
      ],
      [
        "Jenette Caldwell",
        "Development Lead",
        "New York",
        "1937",
        "2011/09/03",
        "$345,000"
      ],
      [
        "Yuri Berry",
        "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)",
        "New York",
        "6154",
        "2009/06/25",
        "$675,000"
      ],
      [
        "Caesar Vance",
        "Pre-Sales Support",
        "New York",
        "8330",
        "2011/12/12",
        "$106,450"
      ],
      [
        "Doris Wilder",
        "Sales Assistant",
        "Sidney",
        "3023",
        "2010/09/20",
        "$85,600"
      ],
      [
        "Angelica Ramos",
        "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
        "London",
        "5797",
        "2009/10/09",
        "$1,200,000"
      ],
      [
        "Gavin Joyce",
        "Developer",
        "Edinburgh",
        "8822",
        "2010/12/22",
        "$92,575"
      ],
      [
        "Jennifer Chang",
        "Regional Director",
        "Singapore",
        "9239",
        "2010/11/14",
        "$357,650"
      ],
      [
        "Brenden Wagner",
        "Software Engineer",
        "San Francisco",
        "1314",
        "2011/06/07",
        "$206,850"
      ],
      [
        "Fiona Green",
        "Chief Operating Officer (COO)",
        "San Francisco",
        "2947",
        "2010/03/11",
        "$850,000"
      ],
      [
        "Shou Itou",
        "Regional Marketing",
        "Tokyo",
        "8899",
        "2011/08/14",
        "$163,000"
      ],
      [
        "Michelle House",
        "Integration Specialist",
        "Sidney",
        "2769",
        "2011/06/02",
        "$95,400"
      ],
      [
        "Suki Burks",
        "Developer",
        "London",
        "6832",
        "2009/10/22",
        "$114,500"
      ],
      [
        "Prescott Bartlett",
        "Technical Author",
        "London",
        "3606",
        "2011/05/07",
        "$145,000"
      ],
      [
        "Gavin Cortez",
        "Team Leader",
        "San Francisco",
        "2860",
        "2008/10/26",
        "$235,500"
      ],
      [
        "Martena Mccray",
        "Post-Sales support",
        "Edinburgh",
        "8240",
        "2011/03/09",
        "$324,050"
      ],
      [
        "Unity Butler",
        "Marketing Designer",
        "San Francisco",
        "5384",
        "2009/12/09",
        "$85,675"
      ],
      [
        "Howard Hatfield",
        "Office Manager",
        "San Francisco",
        "7031",
        "2008/12/16",
        "$164,500"
      ],
      [
        "Hope Fuentes",
        "Secretary",
        "San Francisco",
        "6318",
        "2010/02/12",
        "$109,850"
      ],
      [
        "Vivian Harrell",
        "Financial Controller",
        "San Francisco",
        "9422",
        "2009/02/14",
        "$452,500"
      ],
      [
        "Timothy Mooney",
        "Office Manager",
        "London",
        "7580",
        "2008/12/11",
        "$136,200"
      ],
      [
        "Jackson Bradshaw",
        "Director",
        "New York",
        "1042",
        "2008/09/26",
        "$645,750"
      ],
      [
        "Olivia Liang",
        "Support Engineer",
        "Singapore",
        "2120",
        "2011/02/03",
        "$234,500"
      ],
      [
        "Bruno Nash",
        "Software Engineer",
        "London",
        "6222",
        "2011/05/03",
        "$163,500"
      ],
      [
        "Sakura Yamamoto",
        "Support Engineer",
        "Tokyo",
        "9383",
        "2009/08/19",
        "$139,575"
      ],
      [
        "Thor Walton",
        "Developer",
        "New York",
        "8327",
        "2013/08/11",
        "$98,540"
      ],
      [
        "Finn Camacho",
        "Support Engineer",
        "San Francisco",
        "2927",
        "2009/07/07",
        "$87,500"
      ],
      [
        "Serge Baldwin",
        "Data Coordinator",
        "Singapore",
        "8352",
        "2012/04/09",
        "$138,575"
      ],
      [
        "Zenaida Frank",
        "Software Engineer",
        "New York",
        "7439",
        "2010/01/04",
        "$125,250"
      ],
      [
        "Zorita Serrano",
        "Software Engineer",
        "San Francisco",
        "4389",
        "2012/06/01",
        "$115,000"
      ],
      [
        "Jennifer Acosta",
        "Junior Javascript Developer",
        "Edinburgh",
        "3431",
        "2013/02/01",
        "$75,650"
      ],
      [
        "Cara Stevens",
        "Sales Assistant",
        "New York",
        "3990",
        "2011/12/06",
        "$145,600"
      ],
      [
        "Hermione Butler",
        "Regional Director",
        "London",
        "1016",
        "2011/03/21",
        "$356,250"
      ],
      [
        "Lael Greer",
        "Systems Administrator",
        "London",
        "6733",
        "2009/02/27",
        "$103,500"
      ],
      [
        "Jonas Alexander",
        "Developer",
        "San Francisco",
        "8196",
        "2010/07/14",
        "$86,500"
      ],
      [
        "Shad Decker",
        "Regional Director",
        "Edinburgh",
        "6373",
        "2008/11/13",
        "$183,000"
      ],
      [
        "Michael Bruce",
        "Javascript Developer",
        "Singapore",
        "5384",
        "2011/06/27",
        "$183,000"
      ],
      [
        "Donna Snider",
        "Customer Support",
        "New York",
        "4226",
        "2011/01/25",
        "$112,000"
      ]
    ]
  }
```

add `opal` to `Gemfile`,

```
gem 'opal-rails'

gem 'opal-jquery'
```

`application.js.rb` contents,

```
require 'opal'
require 'jquery'
require 'opal-jquery'
require 'datatables.min'
require_tree '.'
```

add `datatables.min.js` file to `app/assets/javascripts` folder

html,

```
<table id="organizations-datatable" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**NOTE** :- If you want it to work with POST you have to adjust your `config/routes.rb`,

Add the following entry in routes.rb for your json file,

For me it was,

```
post '/data.json', :to => redirect('/data.json')
```

For you it will be,

```
post '/organizations/datatable.json', :to => redirect('/organizations/datatable.json')
```

**Full code here** https://gitlab.com/shoyebsheikh/opal-datatables

**Ajax datatables rails gem solution:**

You can add the following line to your routes assuming thats the data source,

```
post '/organizations/datatable.json', :to => redirect('/organizations/datatable.json')
```

Your controller should be like,

```
class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController
    def datatable
        params["columns"] ||= { "0" => {"data" => "" } }
        params["length"]  ||= -1
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json { render json: OrganizationDatatable.new(params) }
        end
    end
end
```

And your datatable as follows,

```
class OrganizationDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::ActiveRecord

  def view_columns
    # Declare strings in this format: ModelName.column_name
    # or in aliased_join_table.column_name format

    @view_columns ||= {
      # id:       { source: "Organization.id"           },
      name:     { source: "Organization.name",cond: :like, searchable: true, orderable: true          },
      desc:     { source: "Organization.description",cond: :like, searchable: true, orderable: true   },
      industry: { source: "Organization.industry",cond: :like, searchable: true, orderable: true      },
      tags:     { source: "Organization.tag_list", searchable: false, orderable: false      }
    }
  end

  def data
    records.map do |record|
      {
        # id:       record.id,
        name:     record.name,
        desc:     truncate(record.description,length: 240, separator: ' '),
        industry: record.industry,
        tags:     record.decorate.buttonize_tags,
        DT_RowId: record.id
      }
    end
  end

  def get_raw_records
    Organization.all
  end

end
```

In your `organizations.js.rb` goes the opal code,

```
Document.ready? do
  token     = Element['meta[name=csrf-token]'].attr('content');
  settings  = {
      "ajax": {
        "url": Element['#organizations-datatable'].data('source'),
        "type": 'POST',
        "beforeSend": lambda do |xhr|
          `xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token)`
        end 
      },
      "pagingType": "full_numbers",
      "destroy": true,
    "columns": [
      {"data": "name"},
      {"data": "desc"},
      {"data": "industry"},
      {"data": "tags"}
    ]
    }
  Element['#organizations-datatable'].dataTable(settings.to_n)

end
```

And in html,

```
<table id="organizations-datatable" data-source="<%= organizations_index_path(format: :json) %>">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Desc</th>
      <th>Industry</th>
      <th>tags</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

`organizations_index_path` can be `organizations_path` or in singular like `organization_index_path` or `organization_path` depending on your controller name

**Please refer to https://gitlab.com/shoyebsheikh/ajax-datatables-rails-with-opal for more info.**

**Note:**

1. Used mysql2 gem.
2. Run migrations and add entries to the table from
   rails CLI or manually in the table.
3. If you run the project after installing all the dependencies and ran the migration, visit http://localhost:3000/user/index or  http://localhost:3000/hello_world/index

Comment: POST is required to avoid  414 Request-URI Too Large error.

Comment: All the examples I have through of datatables uses GET, when I used POST in this example it was not  recognizing the json file.

Comment: Using POST comes from [this](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails/issues/278) and [this](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails/issues/308#issuecomment-424897335) ... I am using the ajax-datatables-rails  gem and for what it is worth I have datatables working well with POST using javascript. In fact, the javascript snippet in the OP works just fine in Rails.  datatable is populated without a problem, even with the array of objects.  I am literally trying to get Opal to generate the same output.

Comment: I am trying this now to figure this out.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: I am still stuck on this.  I wanted to award you but it didn't solve the issue, which is baffling me.

Comment: Yes.  I've done that.  As I mentioned in the OP, it works for perfectly fine as the OPs Javascript.  I want to understand how to get it to work as Opal.

Comment: @MichaelKMadison its opal and you told me POST is required so I added a code to work it for ajax POST have you seen my edited code ?

Comment: See my routes in the edit, it covers POST and works in javascript but not for Opal.  I'm truly baffled by this.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking my opal works and populates datatables.

Comment: I will evaluate and if so I will open another bounty and give to you.  I have no idea what it means for my environment if this doesn't work for me.

Comment: This does not work for me.  Can you post yours on Github.  I really want to get to the bottom of this.  What version of Opal are you using, etc.

Comment: Dude. Totally thanks so much. Once I look at it will issue another bounty and award to you... about to clone it now.

Comment: Thanks Shoyebh.  This is completely crazy.  Either one of my gems or something else in my environment is messing this up, datatable version. Whatever.  (Maybe rails_ujs? I don't know. I will update this when I do know.) What I know for sure is that you solved this and your repository will help me narrow down whatever it is causing the problem.  For your diligence I am giving twice the original bounty so instead of 50, I will give 100 (on top of losing the original 50).  You went out of your way to help me and that needs to be rewarded.  Thank you so so so much. 100pts is yours after 24h wait.

Comment: Oh, I will add that I was using a lower version of ruby as well.  I will zero in on the variable and figure out what is happening.  And actually your implementation includes the ajax-datatables-rails gem but may not even use it from what I can see. I may take it out completely if it's the reason.

Comment: @MichaelKMadison yes you can take out ajax-datatables-rails gem, I included it coz you mentioned that in your question, but I realized your also not using it, but when I tried to remove that gem it was giving me error so I left it as it is, and yes my code is not using it, glad my code worked for you though.

Comment: Removed ajax-datatables-rails gem successfully and pushed to git project https://gitlab.com/shoyebsheikh/opal-datatables

Comment: Shoyeb yes I am using the ajax-datatables-rails gem I will add my code for it and give you another 200 points if you can get the two to work together (Opal and ajax-datatables-rails)

Comment: OK.  I've added details above. Help me with this and earn another 200 points

Comment: @MichaelKMadison answer updated, used ajax-datatables-rails gem, and added a gitlab project link, try cloning the project and make changes to your code accordingly.

Comment: Shoyeb, just the idea has made me very happy.  Thank you for your diligence, of course I will review and award if it works.

Comment: did you push the update to the same repo? That link takes me to the old repo that doesn't have the gem and hasn't generated the datatable folder or datatable class.

Comment: ok so I see it under your user on gitlab. Just so others also find it -- it is here: https://gitlab.com/shoyebsheikh/ajax-datatables-rails-with-opal

Comment: OK.  I populated the User table and it frickin' works.  I truly have no idea what is wrong with mine but it does use ajax-datatables-rails and Opal.  Sheesh. I'm a man of my word.  Those 200pts. are yours. I assume you will leave the repo up for others or describe it well enough above.

Comment: Thanks again my friend.  Well desserved.

Comment: @MichaelKMadison yeah I am not deleting those two repos, leaving it for others to learn, I am glad I could help, wish you get your project working soon.